# Use of unresolved identifier "success" with SwiftyStoreKit

Tags: ios, swift3, storekit

I'm upgrading myp roject from Swift 2.3 to 3.

Example code from SwiftyStoreKit's Github:

```
.SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct("com.musevisions.SwiftyStoreKit.Purchase1", quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let purchase):
```

my code:

```
func purchase(_ productId : String) {
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
        SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(productId, completion: {
            result in
            NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()
            switch result
            {
            case success(let purchase):
```

(quantity & atomically have default values):

`public class func purchaseProduct(_ productId: String, quantity: Int = 1, atomically: Bool = true, applicationUsername: String = "", completion: @escaping (PurchaseResult) -> Void) {`

Why am I getting an error here?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is an instance of enum `PurchaseResult`. So in your switch you are missing `.` or `PurchaseResult.` before success.

Change this line

```
case success(let purchase):
```

with

```
case .success(let purchase):
```

or

```
case PurchaseResult.success(let purchase):
```